# python pandas date time comparisons

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, pandas

I need to compare the years in a `Series`. The values in the `Series` is like '1996', '2015', '2006-01-02' or '20130101' etc. The code I created is,

```
min_year = col_value_series.min()
max_year = col_value_series.max()

current_year = datetime.date.today().year

res1 = min_year > 1970
res2 = max_year < current_year

return min_year > 1970 and max_year < current_year
```

This code works when the `Series` only contains years value, e.g. '1996', '2003'. But it failed when it is '20030101' or '2006-01-02', so I am wondering how to create a better method to consider the both values.

Update 1. I have tried the following code,

```
col_value_series = pd.to_datetime(col_value_series, infer_datetime_format=True)
min_year = col_value_series.min().year
max_year = col_value_series.max().year

current_year = datetime.date.today().year

res1 = min_year > 1970
res2 = max_year < current_year

return min_year > 1970 and max_year < current_year
```

the code is working fine on the values like '20030101' and '2006-01-02', which are converted to datetime, i.e. '2003-01-01'. But it converted values '1996' or '2015' to '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000001996' and '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002015', which are completely wrong (meaning the years are all 1970 now). So how to resolve the issue.

Update 2. It turns out that the years values were of `int` type, instead of `string`, that's why when the years converted to `datetime`, it became '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000001996'.

Comment: if you convert to `datetime` dtypes then you can call `dt.year` on the series and compare as before

Comment: @EdChum I have updated the OP, using `datetime`, but the years were converted completely wrong to '1970-01-01'

Comment: @daiyue `pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['1996', '2015', '2006-01-02','20130101' ])).dt.year.values` producers `array([1996, 2015, 2006, 2013])` as expected. Can you post a minimal reproducible example with the output you're getting? Pandas 18.0 here.